# Code works even without 'self' attribute in method

Tags: python

In the class below, the self parameter in class method `cost` is replaced with another name 'insta' but still it works. Why?

```
class car():
   model='sedan'
   year=2016
   price=775000

   def cost(insta):
      print "Price of car is: ",insta.price

c1=car()
c1.model='SUV'
c1.year=2017
c1.price=120000
c1.cost()

c2=car()
c2.model='hatchback'
c2.year=2018
c2.price=600000
c2.cost()
```

Comment: Because there is no requirement that that argument be called `self`.

Comment: `c1.cost()` is just syntactic sugar for `car.cost(c1)`, so `c1` is just an argument and like any argument can be called anything. It is just convention that this argument is called `self`.

Answer (score 4):

Naming `self` the first parameter of a class method is nothing more than a convention. Your code is strictly tantamount to:

```
def cost(self):
    print "Price of car is: ",self.price
```

However, this convention is respected everywhere, and although I knew it was only a convention, I think it's the first time I see a code not naming the instance `self`.

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate `c1` to be an object of class `car`, `c1` gets those 3 things (attributes) you gave it: a `model`, a `year`, and a `price`.  In order for `c1` to know that you want its `cost()` method to access its `price` *and not `c2`'s price for example*, you (correctly) defined the `cost()` method to associate the `price` printed with the `price` of the object that `cost()` is called on.

The word `self` is common, perhaps because given Python syntax, when you call a method on a class object with dot notation as in `classObject.classMethod()`, it might feel more like you are "calling `classMethod()` *on* `classObject`" than more typically "passing `someArgument` to `someFunction`" let's say, since you don't put `classObject` inside the parenthesis of `classMethod`.  **But the key piece is the association you make in the class definition** (which will work with "`self`" or "`insta`" or "`puppy`", as long as you use the chosen word consistently).  Perhaps a useful naming that would help illuminate what is going on in this particular context would be

```
def cost(myCar):
    print ("Price of car is: ", myCar.price)
```

since you want the `cost` of `myCar` to be the `price` of `myCar`.  This is what `self` does in a more general (and thus more readable and maintainable) way.